# How to get a list of all company accounts?

Tags: c#, .net, sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

I'm trying to get list of all company accounts using SAP Business One (B1 or BO) Data Interface API (DI API) for .NET.
An account is represented as `ChartOfAccounts` SDK's type.
I can't figure out if there is a way to do something like this (it's how I'm getting the list of items):

```
    var oItem = (Items) Company.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.oItems);
    var oSBObob = (SBObob)Company.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.BoBridge);
    var oRecordSet = oSBObob.GetItemList();
```

But it seems there is no method to similar to `GetItemList()` for accounts in `SBObob` type.

Does anybody know how to get list of company accounts?

Comment: There's no obvious parallel to GetItemList() for GL accounts mentioned in the SDK. You could get a recordset by directly querying the OACT table.

Comment: @Daz: Thank you, I actually implemented it exactly the way you've suggested - please see my answer below. It just seemed to me like a frequent use case of SDK classes and I hoped  its classes may contain a convenience method to perform it without researching of DB schema and relying on the SQL queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented this using a `Recordset` approach by querying `OACT` DB table directly for the list of account keys (`AcctCode` DB field) and then using `ChartOfAccounts`'s  `GetByKey()` method to fill other `ChartOfAccounts`'s fields like this:

```
            var sapAccount = (ChartOfAccounts)Company.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.oChartOfAccounts);
            var oRecordSet = (Recordset)company.GetBusinessObject(BoObjectTypes.BoRecordset);
            oRecordSet.DoQuery("SELECT AcctCode FROM OACT");

            while (!oRecordSet.EoF)
            {
                var key = oRecordSet.Fields.Item(0).Value.ToString();
                sapAccount.GetByKey(key)

                // Now sapAccount is filled with current account data - do something with its fields

                oRecordSet.MoveNext();
            }
```